# How to get the last index of a string value

Tags: c#

Below is the code:

```
PropertyInfo[] requestPropertyInfo;
requestPropertyInfo = typeof(CBNotesInqAndMaintRequest).GetProperties();
```

The CBNotesInqAndMaintRequest contains request data member noteline1---noteline18. once I read the name of one of the data member, I want to get its last index. For eg. If the name of the request object is "noteline8", I want to get the index as 8.

For this I have written the below code:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo reqPropertyInfo in requestPropertyInfo)
{
  index = reqPropertyInfo.Name.LastIndexOf("noteline");
}
```

But the above code is returning the index as 0.

Comment: @KendallFrey Look at his questions. The answers provided tend to be very good, and the OP himself has acknowledged their correctness - just not accepted them. It takes 30 seconds to go back through and accept an answer. Sometimes it just takes prompting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a RegEx solution that doesn't matter what the property name is, but grabs the last digits and returns an integer

```
static int GetLastInteger( string name ) {

    int value;
    if( int.TryParse( name, out value ) ) {
        return value;
    }
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = 
        new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex( @"[^0-9](\d+\b)" );

    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m = 
        r.Match( name );

    string strValue = m.Groups[1].Value;
    value = ( int.Parse( strValue ) );
    return value;
}
```

Usable in your example like so:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo reqPropertyInfo in requestPropertyInfo)
{
  index = GetLastInteger(reqPropertyInfo.Name);
}
```

Comment: May I suggest `\d+$` instead.

Answer (score 3):

It that what you want ?

```
foreach (PropertyInfo reqPropertyInfo in requestPropertyInfo)
{
  index = int.Parse(reqPropertyInfo.Name.Replace("noteline",""));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to get the number after 'noteline'. If that is the case:

```
index = int.Parse(reqPropertyInfo.Name.SubString(8));
```

Comment: I wanted to get the integer part of a name noteline1, noteline2, noteline3,---noteline18(i.e 1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5--18). How will I achieve it

Comment: @HimanshuNegi: This answer shows you how. If `reqPropertyInfo.Name` is `"noteline123"`, then index will become `123`.

Answer (score 2):

```
index = reqPropertyInfo.Name.Length -1;
```

incase of "noteline18", you want to find the index of 1 instead of 8, then

```
index = reqPropertyInfo.Name.LastIndexOf('e') + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting `0` back is that it is returning the last index of the entire string "noteline", which is of course, always at position 0.  If you had "notelinenoteline", it would be returning "8".

Now, as to what you *want* to get back:

```
index = reqPropertyInfo.Name.Substring(8);
```

Answer (score 0):

`LastIndexOf` returns the starting index of the string that you're looking for, which is why it returns 0.

Comment: This will provide the value -1+8. i.e 7. I wanted to get the value 8(if the name is noteline8). If the name is noteline1 then it should provide me 1

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Considering your comment, you should do:

```
Int32 index = Convert.ToInt32(reqPropertyInfo.Name.Replace("noteline",""));
```

Comment: I wanted to get the integer part of a name noteline1, noteline2, noteline3,---noteline18(i.e 1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5--18). How will I achieve it

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer in my opinion is to get the count of the string and then subtract it by 1, will give you the last index of that string as shown below:-

```
int lastIndex= sampleString.Count-1; //sampleString is the string here.
```